# COM or SOM for a Project

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

If you have have a project to create a customized intranet for 200 user (located in different countries), should I use COM or SOM? Maybe both of them?

Comment: there is not enough detail here to help you out.  "customized" does not have to include coding at all if you are using the UI and/or SPD.  I would recomend have a bit more specific use case, to make this a credible question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the decision often depends on what the requirements are; what customizations are being developed.  If it is something like cross-site navigation, or something that will require extensive caching for performance I will typically use the server object model.  If they are relatively simple customizations pulling data from the local site, then I could use either, but would typically pick the standard for the project.

Comment: Is it possibly to use SOM and COM at the same time in a solution in VS2012?

Comment: Yes it is possible to mix the two, you just need to be sure to reference both namespaces.  I'm not sure there would be a benefit to using both the server object model and the client side object model for managed code, but I have mixed server object model with the client side javascript libraries where the main processing is done on the server, and then ajax powered updates done on the client side.